# Applying MySQL binlogs that are too large

Tags: mysql, binlog, mysqlbinlog

I am trying to recover a MySQL crash. I have data as of Monday and binlogs since then, and want to apply the binlogs as the combination would be a complete set of the data. The trouble is that binlogs are read as a single packet. Some of mine are too large, up to 2.4G, while MySQL only allows max_allowed_packet=1G (1073741824). Is there any way to chunk them or otherwise split them up?

I have tried the split Linux command which gives a "bad magic number" error on the second and subsequent files of each split file. After reading on this it makes sense, and that method will not work. I have now tried to use mysqlbinlog --start-position 4 --stop-position 200000003 $1 > $1.binout so I could use a loop with an increment, but it doesn't end on a boundary:

`WARNING: The range of printed events ends with a row event or a table map event that does not have the STMT_END_F flag set. This might be because the last statement was not fully written to the log, or because you are using a --stop-position or --stop-datetime that refers to an event in the middle of a statement. The event(s) from the partial statement have not been written to output.`

When I increment the next loop is there a way to determine what the real start position is? The example ended at 199994536. Is there a way to detect the last position of the resulting binlog?

Comment: Are you saying that there is a single binlog entry of more than 1GB?  The total file size is not an issue; at issue is the size of an entry.